# run script if Date_1 > Date_2

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

sheet example : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r7N-KeQsWjoI945KcrMDJ8skcl4ctglY-8E68as71oE/edit#gid=1301603299

original sheet gets data to col B using IMPORTHTML when ever it changes and i used to do well untill recently when google started to cache some data

i was using

```
if( New !== Old )
```

and was working good so far, but now reverting to previous data and adding old data, then updating when there is new data and so one, messing with other tables that relly on that info

so i tried to change to

```
if( New > Old)
```

script:

```
function doUpBalanco() 
{
  
// get input sheet
  const SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Balanço');
 
    const New = SS.getRange('B1').getValue();
    const Old = SS.getRange('C1').getValue();

    var LR = SS.getLastRow();
    var LC = SS.getLastColumn();

  if( New !== "-" )  //check if error  //  Balanço
  {
     if( New > Old)  // check if data changed // Balanço
    {
      if( Old == "" )  // check if table is blank // YES // Balanço
      {
        var Data_New_1 = SS.getRange(1,2,LR,1).getValues();
        SS.getRange(1,3,LR,1).setValues(Data_New_1);
      }
      else                 // check if table is blank // NO // Balanço
      {
        var Data_New_1 = SS.getRange(1,2,LR,1).getValues();
        var Data_Backup = SS.getRange(1,3,LR,LC-2).getValues();
        SS.getRange(1,4,LR,LC-2).setValues(Data_Backup);

        SS.getRange(1,3,LR,1).setValues(Data_New_1);
      }
    } 
  }  
};
```

its not running as its not reconizing as B1 > C1

but if i change old to D1, it does run

as it shows on my check on lines 25 - 28

im not using getDisplayValue but getValue, so im kinda lost

the rest of the script works well, im basicly just failing to see whats wrong with that check

any insight is much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I confirmed that the value of `New` and `Old` are the string values like `31/03/2021` and `31/12/2020`. If your actual situation is the same with this sample Spreadsheet, from this situation, when you want to compare `New > Old`, I would like to propose to convert the string value to the date object. By this, `New > Old` can be used. And, when the values of `New` and `Old` are retrieved by one request, I thought that the process cost will become a bit low. When these points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

##### From:

```
const New = SS.getRange('B1').getValue();
const Old = SS.getRange('C1').getValue();
```

##### To:

```
const values = SS.getRange('B1:C1').getValues()[0];
const [[NewD, NewM, NewY], [OldD, OldM, OldY]] = values.map(v => v ? v.split("/") : Array(3).fill(""));
const New = NewD && NewM && NewY ? new Date(NewY, NewM - 1, NewD).getTime() : "";
const Old = OldD && OldM && OldY ? new Date(OldY, OldM - 1, OldD).getTime() : "";
```

#### Note:

- If at your actual situation, the values of `New` and `Old` are the date object, you can also the following modification.

  - From

    ```
      const New = SS.getRange('B1').getValue();
      const Old = SS.getRange('C1').getValue();
    ```
  - To

    ```
      const values = SS.getRange('B1:C1').getValues()[0];
      const [New, Old] = values.map(v => v ? v.getTime() : "");
    ```

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

Comment: thanks solved my problem, i would never be able to come up with something like that, if its not too much to ask, how should i do, if its not consecutive range, i mean on another table i use cols B and C ( C if for other purpose) to compare, and result is copied to col D onwards, so getRange('B1:C1') woulnd do as i would need to compare B and D, i worked around it doing B1:D1 and adding a fake constant beetwen, but im trying to learn not just get things done

Comment: @Bruno Carvalho Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 2):

To compare dates numerically use [Date().valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) or [Date().getTime();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)